# Position fixed - what next?

Tags: html, css

I've made a menu that should stick to the left all the time with the code below.

```
.menu {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200); 
}
```

Now I want my text to appear besides my menu.

Got a jsfiddle of the problem also.
http://jsfiddle.net/7cpz80er/

Comment: it's fixed, so it's removed from the document "flow". if you want to text to flow around your menu to the right of the menu, then you'll have to use a different positioning scheme.

Comment: @MarcB What would you recommend then? I want it to be sticked to the left all the time.

Comment: you could do a padding to the left of the site container `padding: 220px` the only problem is this is a defined width and won't be flexible so you would have to account for that later

Comment: Yeah @CayceK thats an idea but thats not the best way to do it i guess?

Comment: its the best idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Cayce K said, you can use `padding` on your content with a full width. For mobile, you can always hide the nav on the left, and add a button to open it.

Quick Mocup: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cpz80er/3/)

Resize the window, and you will see the effect.

```
#open {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 50px;
}
.test {
    padding-left: 220px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 3000px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 30em) {
    .menu-wrapper {
        display: none;
    }
    .test {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    #open {
        display: block;
    }
}
.showButton {
    display: block;
}
```

JQuery example of open menu button:

```
$('#open').click(function () {
    $('.menu-wrapper').toggleClass('showButton');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, thats will work fine!

@Cayace K thanks also for your help.